# Generate random pairs of numbers, without duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, random, combinations

I have to arrays with integers:

```
int[] a={1,2,3,4,5};
int[] b={6,7};
```

I would like to generate an array, which contains pairs from the a and b arrays, in a random order, without duplicates. For example I would like to get the following result:

```
c={(1,6),(2,7),(4,6),...}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try something already?

Comment: Not yet, just tried to look around for tutorials, because I have no idea how can I do the pairs thing.

Comment: create a class called Pair . then u'll be able to answer your own question.

Comment: Pseudo: pair each number in `a` with each number of `b`. How does it sound in terms of loops? :)

Comment: Is this an interview question? What have you tried? We are not here to solve your problems, but to help if you are stuck with your solution. It looks like that you haven't tackled this one yet.

Comment: I understand that, I just wanted to get some suggestions, how to solve this problem, I'm not asking for a complete solution.

Comment: Lucky day for you.  I gave you a complete solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code which creates 10 random pairs from your input `a[]` and `b[]` arrays, and stores them into an `HashSet` which you can use later as you see fit.  The `HashSet` will automatically remove duplicate pairs.

```
public class Pair {
    int x;
    int y;

    public Pair(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Pair otherPair = (Pair) obj;
        if (this.getX() != otherPair.getX() || this.getY() != otherPair.getY()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // getters and setters
}

public class PairTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        int[] a={1,2,3,4,5};
        int[] b={6,7};

        Set<Pair> pairs = new HashSet<Pair>();

        do {
            int xRand = randomGenerator.nextInt(a.length);
            int yRand = randomGenerator.nextInt(b.length);

            Pair p;
            if (xRand % 2 == 0) {
                Pair p = new Pair(a[xRand], b[yRand]);
            }
            else {
                Pair p = new Pair(b[yRand], a[xRand]);
            }
            pairs.add(p);
            if (pairs.size() == 10) break;
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this prevent duplicates? The question states no duplicates.

Comment: For the duplicates you could replace the ArrayList with a HashSet and override the Pair.equals() method.

Comment: His OP is a bit contrieved since there are only 10 possible unique pairs.  But my solution is a good template for him to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

```
    int[] a={1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] b={6,7};
    List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; ++j)
            list.add(new int[] {a[i], b[j]});
    Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do I guess. I added a toString to the Pair class and at the end of the main so you can see the output

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class Pair {

    private Integer a;
    private Integer b;

    public Pair(Integer a, Integer b) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Integer getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(Integer a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public Integer getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(Integer b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pair [a=" + a + ", b=" + b + "]";
    }


}

public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();

        int[] a={1,2,3,4,5};
        int[] b={6,7};

        for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
            pairs.add(new Pair(a[i], b[(int) Math.round(Math.random())]));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(pairs);
        System.out.println(pairs);

    }

}
```

Comment: The way you set `a` isn't random.

Comment: `b[(int) Math.round(Math.random())]` gulp... Looks terrible to me. Better use [ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: @Sionnach733 sry forgot to add a shuffle to the list :d

Comment: @bratkartoffel thanks, I just made it up on the spot and didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0):

If an random array is good enough for you, this is IMO the most simple way: Just create all possible pairs and shuffle the result, that will grand randomness and uniqueness as long as `a` and `b` contain unique values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] b = { 6, 7 };

    ArrayList<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            pairs.add(new Pair(a[i], b[j]));
        }
    }

    Collections.shuffle(pairs);

    Pair[] asArray = pairs.toArray(new Pair[0]); //if you prefer array over ArrayList
}

class Pair {
    int a, b;

    public Pair(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

If you would like to generate less pairs that the total amount of pairs possible, there are more effective ways then to generate them all and then just take the first few. If so, write in the comments.